# global struct and multiple threads in c

Tags: c, windows, struct, global

can someone explain me the compilation error in this code:

```
#include "common.h"

typedef struct nodeData {
    int procid;
    unsigned short localport;
    DWORD LIFETIME;
    DWORD HELLOTIMEOUT;
    DWORD MAXTIME;
} nodeData;

int listenerThread() {
    if(!bindSocket(listenSocket,nodeData.localport)){
        closesocket(listenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(-1);
}
    // more code goes here  
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
    nodeData.localport = 5001;
    // more code goes here  

}
```

I want the nodeData struct to be available to every listenerThread I will create. threads are going to manipulate this nodeData struct all the time (will protect it with a mutex).

so i want this struct to be availabe globally. where do i initialize it ? my guess is in main.

the compilation error in the line

```
nodeData.localport = 5001;
```

is

> error: a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

what am i'm missing here ?

thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`nodeData` is a type not a variable - since you `typedef` it. Try e.g:

```
typedef struct nodeData_t {
    int procid;
    unsigned short localport;
    DWORD LIFETIME;
    DWORD HELLOTIMEOUT;
    DWORD MAXTIME;
} nodeData;

nodeData MyNodeData;
```

And then use the *variable* `MyNodeData`

Comment: I *swear* I didn't lift your answer :) ... we just apparently use the same camel case.

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick reply. forgive me for the ignorance, but it always confuses me, isn't writing the nodeData just after defining the struct already creating an instance of it ?

Comment: @michael: No, not when you have `typedef` in front. `struct nodeData {} MyNodeData;` would create an instance

Comment: @Erik, i see thanks. and what is nodeData_t representing ? i'm not familiar with this syntax. is it just to differeniate nodeData the struc from nodeData that comes after the struct declaration ?

Comment: @michael: Yep. Personally I never ever use the same name for a struct, it's typedef and an instance.

Comment: @michael: you can (maybe you should) use separate lines for all of defining a type, creating an alias, defining an object. `struct whatever_tag {/*members*/};`; `typedef struct whatever_tag whatever;`; `whatever object = {0};`

Answer (score 1):

Without going into why you shouldn't use a global for this, you haven't created a global variable anywhere, only defined a structure and typedef'd it.

Prior to main you would need to do:

```
nodeData myNodeData;
```

And access it as `myNodeData`

Comment: thanks, what do you suggest i do instead ? should i define the struct inside main ? would the other threads called from main be able to use it ?

Comment: Typically you want to avoid globals. Not only from a memory standpoint but for readability and data encapsulation. Instantiating the struct in main and passing a pointer to it to your threads would be the common approach.

Comment: how would the thread know a struct that was defined in main ? the thread is not defined in the same scope of main...

Comment: Then you would instantiate it wherever you're creating your threads. If you returning to main after that, you would either need to create it on the heap with `malloc` to avoid scoping issues, or still instantiate it in main and pass a pointer up through to where you're creating your threads. (Without seeing your code, that's a hard question to answer specifically). On the subject of globals, this is a fairly good read: [Global Variables are Bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad)